# Which object has been to space the most times?

Tags: record, karman-line, trivia

Which particular piece of hardware has crossed the Karman line most often?

By hardware I mean anything other than organisms.

Comment: Do you mean the physically same piece of hardware or the same model of something that's been built multiple times?

Comment: That, obviously, would be one of the Shuttles (less the tiles, of course).

Comment: I suppose there *could be* an aircraft that's done ballistic trajectories to 100 km more than once, but not sure if it could be more times than a Shuttle. [How did the X-15 control attitude above the Kármán line?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31412/12102)

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/what-objects-have-been-sent-to-space-twice — I still like Jerry Ross’s wristwatch for this.

Comment: My guess, which I'm having a bit of trouble backing up with actual data, is that we're looking for something doing some elliptical de-orbiting aerobraking over multiple passes.

Comment: Any chance a space suit flew more than 39 times?

Comment: I'd be very unsurprised if a piece of Soyuz equipment, like the survival box, was retrieved from the landed capsule and reused on next launch enough times to breach the record.

Comment: @SF. Although it would make practical sense to reuse the survival kit, it seems the real fate of those (at least the gun itself) was a bit different: “At the end of the mission, after landing, the gun is usually presented as a gift to the Soyuz spacecraft commander,” Source: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.businessinsider.com.au/this-is-a-triple-barreled-soviet-space-gun-with-an-attached-machete-2015-1/amp&ved=2ahUKEwjB-rGOnp3mAhWRfH0KHdhpA7oQFjANegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2Ks7b4uauAQmh61vrcKgrd&ampcf=1

Comment: There were more than 50 KH-8 missions, each with two film return capsules. I wonder if any of the parts from them were re-used?

Comment: A tangential question would be if the *inclusion* of organisms changes the answer in any way.

Comment: @Dragongeek I mean the physically same piece

Comment: @Hohmannfan feel free to follow up :) I excluded organisms because this question occurred to me while reading about which people visited space most often. As the record for humans is 7 times, and as I read Justin Braun's answer, I hardly doubt the inclusion of organisms to this question would change anything.

Comment: I think there's also a question of how 'theseus ship' we want to get, certain craft like the space shuttle underwent extensive part changes even though it's still the same ship

Comment: Is it just me, or does anyone else see Elon Musk reading this question and replying with "Challenge Accepted"?

Answer (score 46):

The Space Shuttle Discovery has been to orbit a total number of 39 times, more than any other shuttle vehicle (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions#Flight_statistics)). Contrasting that to other candidate objects:

- Space Shuttles Atlantis, Columbia, Endeavour and Challenger flew 33, 28, 25 and 10 missions, respectively.
- [Spacelab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacelab) pressurized module LM1 flew a total of 10 times.
- Falcon 9 first stage [B1048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_first-stage_boosters) has been used a total of 4 times and has not exceeded the Karman line in any of those flights
- The X-15-1 flew a total of 81 times, however it never exceeded the Karman line as the highest altitude it ever reached was 267,500 ft. X-15-3 did exceed the Karman line twice.
- The [X-37b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-37) has flown a total of 5 times, however a single vehicle has only flown 3 times

Comment: What about the other Space Shuttles? Those would be obvious candidates.

Comment: They have fewer missions.

Comment: I still wonder about piece-parts. The SSME that flew the most missions flew ~20 times. But some laptop, swizzle stick, etc...who knows? Hard to track down.

Comment: X-15 have made two flights above the Karman line, Flight 90 at 105.9 km and Flight 91 at 107.8 km, both by Joseph A. Walker. Others are, however, below, with Flight 62 being at 95.9 km so almost.

Comment: Other things that have been to space multiple times: Westar 6 / AsiaSat 1, which was retrieved by the Shuttle and subsequently relaunched; several pieces of SpaceX hardware have been reflown above the Karman line (one Dragon capsule was reflown, as was one fairing); and if you count humans as objects, Jerry Ross and Franklin Díaz have both been to space 7 times.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez you can see a spreadsheet showing the missions of all the orbiters here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25415/6944

Comment: @DiegoSánchez it's not clear what you mean by "*the only one mentioned is Discovery*'; the linked evidence shows it is the one with the highest number of flights indeed among the shuttle vehicles.

Comment: I wonder if it could be something mundane like the containers they use to ship supplies (food, etc.) to the ISS?  I'd assume they get sent back empty (or possibly with waste materials), since they'd just be wasting the limited space up there, and possibly they'd get reused on future resupply missions.

Comment: `-1`I think that by asking "Which particular piece of hardware..." the OP is indeed asking specifically about individual bits, rather than only for entire spacecraft.

Comment: @uhoh then, it would be: All the pieces of Discovery hardware that weren't replaced a single time since it's been built (the obvious one I can think of is the internal structural frame). But that might deserve another question.

Comment: @LeoS Can that be somehow confirmed that there is indeed no "particular piece of hardware" that was moved from one shuttle to another in order to get it into space more frequently?

Comment: If you want to be technically correct on the "replacement parts" certain shuttle tiles flew on all of the flights and were never replaced.

Comment: New Shepard has flown 11 times, across three boosters.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Empty containers will go with all the other trash, which is burnt up in the atmosphere - not reused.

Comment: I checked on SRB segments but they didn't even get Air Force astronaut wings.

Comment: @uhoh you are right, but this is still a good answer

Comment: @uhoh, with that narrow interpretation of the question, the technically correct answer would be "The Shuttle Orbiter Discovery's frame, and every piece of hardware mounted to it which hasn't been replaced during the orbiter's lifetime."  I think this answer gets that point across well enough, as well as provides supplemental information for anyone with similar questions.

Comment: @Ghedipunk I'm thinking [about this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40244/which-object-has-been-to-space-the-most-times/40248?noredirect=1#comment130447_40248)

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Well if you worked for NASA and *you* don't know, then I think we can rule out there being some intentionally sanctified object that would answer this question. I think the swizzle stick would've 'disappeared' way before 40 w/o there being a paper trail for its provenance, and if there was a trail *you* would know about it.

Comment: @Mazura NASA is(was) vast and I only knew one little corner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all, or almost all Falcon first stages actually make it to space, they just might not until after separation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101889/discussion-on-answer-by-justin-braun-which-object-has-been-to-space-the-most-tim).

Comment: More accurate data on New Shepard: the second craft flew five times; the third craft flew five times and is shooting for a sixth tomorrow.

Comment: Several SpaceX Dragon capsules have been reused as well, 2 have been flown 3 times.